# Downgrade kernel in CentOS from 3.10.0-862.3.3 to 3.10.0-693.5.2, how to resolve missing dependencies?

Tags: centos

I have CentOS 7 installed with Kernel 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64, but due to possible compatibilty issues I need 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64. How can I downgrade?

I've tried to look for the yum package with `yum list --showduplicates kernel-*`, but this only gives me the current 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7 as option.

I've tried downloading the rpm itself and installing it, but it says there is nothing to do:

```
[root@ci4 tmp]# wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/scientificlinux/7.1/x86_64/updates/security/kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
[root@ci4 tmp]# yum downgrade ./kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining ./kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
Package kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 is allowed multiple installs, skipping
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've tried with rpm

```
[root@ci4 tmp]# rpm -Uvh --oldpackage kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r10) = 0x7e526bfa is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r12) = 0x263ed23b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r13) = 0xe7b00dfb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r14) = 0xce8b1878 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r15) = 0x0f05c7b8 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r8) = 0x1ed8b599 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r9) = 0xdf566a59 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rax) = 0x2ea2c95c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rbx) = 0x593c1bac is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rcx) = 0xc29957c3 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rdx) = 0xb601be4c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rsi) = 0xa1f9a134 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xf3d46cd5 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_put_device) = 0xa767fd96 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xcf368f2b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x62b8c739 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(sme_me_mask) = 0x17fbce60 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r10) = 0x7e526bfa is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r12) = 0x263ed23b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r13) = 0xe7b00dfb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r14) = 0xce8b1878 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r15) = 0x0f05c7b8 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r8) = 0x1ed8b599 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r9) = 0xdf566a59 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rax) = 0x2ea2c95c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rbx) = 0x593c1bac is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rcx) = 0xc29957c3 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rdx) = 0xb601be4c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rsi) = 0xa1f9a134 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xf3d46cd5 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_put_device) = 0xa767fd96 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xcf368f2b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x62b8c739 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(sme_me_mask) = 0x17fbce60 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r10) = 0x7e526bfa is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r12) = 0x263ed23b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r13) = 0xe7b00dfb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r14) = 0xce8b1878 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r15) = 0x0f05c7b8 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r8) = 0x1ed8b599 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r9) = 0xdf566a59 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rax) = 0x2ea2c95c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rbx) = 0x593c1bac is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rcx) = 0xc29957c3 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rdx) = 0xb601be4c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rsi) = 0xa1f9a134 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xf3d46cd5 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_put_device) = 0xa767fd96 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xcf368f2b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x62b8c739 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
    kernel(sme_me_mask) = 0x17fbce60 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.0.168-16.el7_5.x86_64
```

I've tried resolving the missing dependencies by disabling the current CentOS 7 repository and enabling the Vault repository. I've added `enabled=0` to every entry in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and set `enabled=1` to every entry in `vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo` containing `CentOS-7.4.1708`. Still I'm getting the same result when using rpm or yum to downgrade the kernel.

Comment: Use `rpm`, beware of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The two kernels you reference, `3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64` and `3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64`, represent CentOS 7.5 and CentOS 7.4 respectively.  CentOS moves the older kernel packages to the [CentOS vault](http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm) when they are not current.

To get YUM to use the vault you would need to disable your current CentOS `base` and `updates` repositories, and then replace them with their version 7.4 counterparts from the CentOS vault (i.e. `baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/updates/$basearch/`).  After that is set up correctly, you should be able to use `yum downgrade kernel`.  You may also be required to downgrade any packages that relied on the newer kernel version.

Comment: I've updated my question. Did I correctly disable an enable the repositories?

Comment: did you update the YUM cache after enabling the new repositories?  does it see the older version of the kernel?  What is the output from `yum repolist` and `yum info kernel`?  Also, it just occurred to me that you may already have that version of the kernel installed (check with `rpm -q kernel`).  If that is the case, just reboot into the older kernel and see if that fixes your compatibility issues.